# Slice getting updated magically

Tags: algorithm, go, binary-tree, slice

I am trying to write a program to find all root-to-leaf paths in a binary tree where each path's sum equals the given sum.

Following is the code I have come up with

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type TreeNode struct {
     Val int
     Left *TreeNode
     Right *TreeNode
}

func main() {
    root := TreeNode{
       Val : 5,
       Left: &TreeNode { 
           Val : 4,
           Left : &TreeNode {
                Val : 11,
                Left : &TreeNode { Val : 2},
                Right : &TreeNode { Val : 7},
            
            },
        
        },
    }
    
    paths := [][]int{}
    pathSumRecursive(&root, 22, []int{}, &paths)
    fmt.Println("paths:", paths)
}


func pathSumRecursive(root *TreeNode, sum int, currentPath []int, paths *[][]int) {
    if root == nil {
        return 
    }
    
    currentPath = append(currentPath, root.Val)
    
    if root.Left == nil && root.Right == nil && root.Val == sum {
        *paths = append(*paths, currentPath)
        fmt.Println("paths updated ", *paths)
        return
    } 
    
    pathSumRecursive(root.Left, sum-root.Val, currentPath, paths) 
    pathSumRecursive(root.Right, sum-root.Val, currentPath, paths)
    
}
```

Output of this program is

```
paths updated  [[5 4 11 2]]
paths: [[5 4 11 7]]
```

[Play ground Link](https://play.golang.org/p/NYenE9iBYMO)

What I do not understand is the value which was appended to `paths` was `[5 4 11 2]` and it was updated only once. So what caused the `2` (last element) to get updated to `7`?

I understand that the slices are passed by value and a slice value is a header, describing a contiguous section of a backing array. But I still don't understand how the value got replaced in the subsequent recursion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Slices in Go are small descriptors containing a pointer to the underlying array, a length, and a capacity. See [Slice internals](https://blog.golang.org/slices-intro) for more details.

When a slice is passed to a function, the descriptor is copied but the underlying array is not. This means that `currentPath` will always point to the same underlying array but will have various values through the recursion:

- at node `11`: `currentPath = [5 4 11]`
- at node `2`: `currentPath =  [5 4 11 2]`. Added to `paths` with length 4.
- back up to node `11`: `currentPath = [5 4 11]`
- at node `7`: `currentPath = [5 4 2 7]`.

In node `7`, the underlying array is still the same and shared with the slice stored in `paths`. But node 7 now appends `7` to the slice of length 3, overwriting the previous value of `2` in the underlying array.

One quick solution to this is to copy the contents of `currentPath` into `path` rather than store the slice directly:

```golang
    if root.Left == nil && root.Right == nil && root.Val == sum {
        newSlice := make([]int, len(currentPath))
        copy(newSlice, currentPath)
        *paths = append(*paths, newSlice)
        fmt.Println("paths updated ", *paths)
        return
    }
```

**Important note**: when a slice needs to grow, the underlying array is copied, resulting a separate arrays. In the example, the slice is grown to a capacity of 4 at node `4` so it remains the same underlying array at nodes `2` and `7`. Should it be grown at node `2`, the slice added to `path` would not share its underlying array with anyone.

Comment: I agree that copying the current elements and then attaching them would work. But I don't agree with your explanation. Going by that logic this anomaly should be seen here as well https://play.golang.org/p/C10vXXadrRt. Just made the tree smaller. But it doesn't.
You would expect the answer to be `[5,4,7]` but it is `[5,4,2]` . Why doesn't it override here.

Comment: Because Go ended up allocating more space to the underlying array, separating them. Print `cap(currentPath)` before/after each `currentPath = append(currentPath, root.Val)`. In the first example, the underlying array grew at a previous node and is the same between `2` and `7`. In the second case, the `2` node grows the array, so it's now separate. When growing a slice, the underlying array gets copied (it has to).

Comment: I recommend you read [slice internals](https://blog.golang.org/slices-intro) very carefully, it seems you missed some important aspects.

Comment: I am still not convinced with the `cap` argument. I used the invocation of method as `pathSumRecursive(&root, 22, make([]int, 0, 5), &paths)` so that all capacity is pre-allocated. But it still overrides the value. I take your recommendation of reading slice internals carefully.  Will update this if I find something.

Comment: If you create a slice of capacity 5, then the underlying array will always be the same, and you'll see the value being overwritten.